# How can I load, edit, and overwrite jpg files with Darktable?

Tags: software, jpeg, workflow, darktable

This is a follow up to a question asked on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/708759/color-adjustment-for-100-jpg-files-fast-workflow-for-savenext

I want to do manual color adjustment for 100 jpg files.

The workflow I use at the moment works like this:

1. open first jpg
2. do manual color adjustment. Either "auto" or "curves"
3. load next jpg

I want to do a **manual** correction of each photo. This question is not about batch processing.

I want the switching (save current, go to next) to be fast as using a flipbook.

Up to now I used gimp, but I think switching to darktable has a lot of benefits.

I know that perfectionists don't do "load jpg, edit jpg, overwrite jpg". But I am not a perfectionist. I want to do it this way (sometimes).

**Question**

How to overwrite to source jpg files with darktable?

Comment: It's worth noting that the reason this workflow is slightly awkward in darktable is because it's designed entirely around the concept of "non-destructive editing", where the original (typically RAW) file is normally never modified.

Answer (score 3):

Darktable isn't really set up to do this. A lot of modern workflow software like this is "opinionated" — it's set up with a certain way of doing things in mind, and designed intentionally around that, rather than providing a toolbox of options. In Darktable's case, that workflow is non-destructive editing — basically the opposite of what you're going for.

But that said, in this particular case, there's an easy way to do things which is *similar* to what you're asking for and should give decent results. Import all your images in whatever way you want (`darktable *.jpg` on the command line), and make all the changes to each one. When you're done, enter $(FILE_FOLDER)/$(FILE_NAME) as the output, select all the images, and then press export. You'll need to check "overwrite" each time (but not for each file separately), presumably as a safety feature.

I don't think that Darktable has a way a to match JPEG output quality to input quality, though, and for the kind of thing you're talking about that might be a deal-breaker.

Comment: You can also just keep the placeholders $(FILE_FOLDER)/$(FILE_NAME) set as the output, and check the 'overwrite' box before hitting 'export'. The checkbox unchecks itself after the export operation, I'm assuming this is an intentional safety feature.

Comment: Ah, cool, I didn't know $(FILE_FOLDER) worked.